# QuickBlox SDK creating and updating privacy list (block/unblock user)

Tags: ios, quickblox

I need to know that how we can edit the existing privacy list, in QuickBlox iOS SDK.

I'm adding items to the Privacy list by using code snippet given in QuickBlox SDK.

```
QBPrivacyItem *item = [[QBPrivacyItem alloc] initWithType:USER_ID valueForType:[self.connectedUserInfo.qbid integerValue] action:DENY];

if (blockPrivacyList) {

[blockPrivacyList addObject:item]; // add new user if already privacy list is there

}else{

  blockPrivacyList = [[QBPrivacyList alloc] initWithName:@"public" items:@[item]]; // create new privacy list if not before created
}

isBlocked = YES;

[[QBChat instance] setPrivacyList:blockPrivacyList];

[[QBChat instance] setActivePrivacyListWithName:@"public"];
```

I'm executing code above to block user or deny user from sending message.

Now I want to unblock that user and want to remove that user from the privacy list.

For that we are executing below code snippet,

```
QBPrivacyItem *item = [[QBPrivacyItem alloc] initWithType:USER_ID valueForType:[self.connectedUserInfo.qbid integerValue] action:ALLOW];

if (blockPrivacyList) {

[blockPrivacyList addObject:item]; // add new user if already privacy list is there

}else{

blockPrivacyList = [[QBPrivacyList alloc] initWithName:@"public" items:@[item]]; // create new privacy list if not before created

}  
isBlocked = NO;

[[QBChat instance] setPrivacyList:blockPrivacyList];

[[QBChat instance] setActivePrivacyListWithName:@"public"];
```

But here another item get added to the privacy list, rather than existing record modification.

Can anyone have idea where I'm doing wrong, so I can re-write stable code.

we are getting below xml stanza after unblocking user 
    IQ SNT:

```html
<iq type="set" id="BE23FB84-C3C8-47F2-94C4-B3F8A042B16C">  
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy">
       <list name="public">
           <item type="jid" value="7520742-30613@chat.quickblox.com" action="deny" order="1">
           </item>
           <item type="jid" value="7520742-30613@chat.quickblox.com" action="allow" order="2">
            </item>
       </list>
    </query>
 </iq>
```

Comment: Delete previous item from the list by yourself, this bug is know currently and will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: how to delete item in QBPrivacyList